# Polygon detection on cardiovascular patterns in Spectograms?

Tags: feature-detection

This [paper *Heart energy signature spectrogram for cardiovascular diagnosis*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1899182/) uses some external software to detect the patterns. I understand this such that A, B and C pictures are used to locate the peaks for D. Does there exist any ready libraries on Matlab for this?

[image]

**How can you computationally detect the cardiovascular patterns in spectrograms?**